# Re-calculate the items inside a `NSArray` then reload the `UITableView`

Tags: uitableview, nsarray

I have two arrays:

array1: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

array2: 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4

every two letters (stations) add $2.
these two arrays will populate in a `UITableView`, whenever a user tap on a `UITableViewCell` (`didSelectedRow`), the array2 will be arranged. For example:

both array items are linked to a `UILabelView`, and the cells are look like

```
[A......1]
[B......1]
[C......2]
[D......2]
[E......3] 
[F......3]
[G......4]
[H......4]
```

taps F, the order will be 3,3,2,2,1,1,1,2

```
[A......3]
[B......3]
[C......2]
[D......2]
[E......1]
[F......1]
[G......1]
[H......2]
```

taps C, the order will be 2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3

taps H, the order will be 4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1

What is the best way to update those data?

Thanks.